# Plotting multiple images in the same pane in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

How do I plot multiple images in same pane? For example I want to plot 8 graphs varying the simulated peak characteristics:

```
import numpy
import peakutils
from peakutils.plot import plot as pplot
from matplotlib import pyplot

#centers = (30.5, 72.3)
centers = (100, 72.3)
x = numpy.linspace(0, 120, 121)
y = (peakutils.gaussian(x, 5, centers[0], 3) +
    peakutils.gaussian(x, 7, centers[1], 10) +
    numpy.random.rand(x.size))
#pyplot.figure(figsize=(10,6))
#pyplot.plot(x, y)
#pyplot.title("Data with noise")
#pyplot._show()

indexes = peakutils.indexes(y, thres=0.5, min_dist=12)
print(indexes)
print(x[indexes], y[indexes])
pyplot.figure(figsize=(10,6))
pplot(x, y, indexes)
pyplot.title('First estimate')
pyplot.show()
```

so I want 8 plots with different centers1 = (100, 72.3), centers2 = (82,23) etc

Comment: Be more precise. You are probably asking for subplots, maybe for their arguments ```sharedx``` and co. I will add the matplotlib-tag, but improve your question.

Comment: In addition to @sascha - Do you want to have different graphs, lines, circles etc. in the same diagram?

Comment: Yes sub plots or different graphs

Comment: And what's wrong with the [official examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html)? Especially the second last one (array-based).